# Recover Mac Mini

Tags: restore, system-restore, password-recovery, system-recovery

I was given a Mac Mini. It uses only 110 VAC power & has a CD/DVD drive. Don't see a model number. It boots up, but the previous owner's ID and password requirement render it useless. I am using a K400 USB keyboard. It lets me type a password, showing dots, so it works that far. I'd like to put a new OS X it. Is there a "Recovery" program on the HDD like windows now does? I can't seem to get to it with the Ctrl, Alt, Shift or Wondows keys held on boot. (One at a time, 4 tries.) I don't want the previous owner's information. A complete reset is OK.

Ctrl-R, Alt-R & Windows-R don't work. Holding Alt, on boot allows selecting a Wi-Fi & shows Mac HD. Picking HD takes me to the Login screen. Selecting a Wi-Fi allows me to test the keyboard. It seems to work, but typing an SSID, Shift-A produces "A" & Alt-a, Ctrl-a & Windows-a all produce "a" Is this normal? It is a PC kayboard!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to reset it by holding command r on reboot, with your keyboard that may be control r, windows key r or alt r.  When it boots it should give you the option to reinstall macos. https://www.imore.com/how-to-prepare-mac-for-sale